# patch endpoint naming and realisation

Tags: rest, endpoint, naming

We have rest resource

```
/tasks/{task-type}
```

and only GET methods available.

```
GET /tasks/{task-type} 
GET /tasks/{task-type}/{id}
```

Task entity contains meta info like created, finished, status, ref key and try counts for scheduled tasks.
Now we faced with problem, when task may contains incorrect data and its execution always failed.
Due to scheduler invoked tasks every 5 min there are a lot of errors in logs and largest try counts around 500k. The solution i found is to limit try_count to five (for example). And now we need way to manual discard try-count to zero. So i found two solutions:

1.

```
PATCH /tasks/{task-type}/{id}/discard-try-count - no response body
```

This solution look pretty simple, but violates the REST convention, because we use action(verb) in naming. But if we need to change other fields, then we will make a lot of endpoints in this style.

2a.

```
PATCH /tasks/{task-type}/{id}
body:
{
   "tryCounts": int
}
```

This looks like REST want to see it and we can easy add new fields to modify, but now client can set any value for tryCount.

2b

```
PATCH /tasks/{task-type}/{id}
body:
{
   "tryCounts": int // validate that try count can be only zero
}
```

Differs from the previous one by the presence of validation.
This looks like the most reliable solution. Is it really the best fit?

Answer (score 0):

The non-verb convention is not a standard, you can violate it if you want to, though it can be worked around with very simple stuff, just convert the verb into a noun and you will be ok, something like:

```
POST /tasks/{task-type}/{id}/try-count-discarding
```

Another way is setting the try count to zero:

```
PUT /tasks/{task-type}/{id}/try-count 0
```

Yet another solution is combining the two, which I like the most:

```
PATCH /tasks/{task-type}/{id}/try-count {"op": "reset"}
```

Or another variant:

```
PATCH /tasks/{task-type}/{id} {"op": "discard-try-count"}
```